# Xamarin: ServiceStack WebServiceException 'Type definitions should start with a {' Only appears on device

Tags: ios, serialization, xamarin, servicestack

So I have been using ServiceStack for our app for several months now and haven't experienced any problems. But for the past few days I've been getting this strange exception when I run my application. However, this error only occurs when I run on the physical iOS device, the simulator works fine and the exception never shows up. This is the exception I'm currently getting

```
{ServiceStack.WebServiceException: Bad Request ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'ErrorResponse', got string starting with: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"" at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJson.StringToType
```

Heres a gist for the entire exception https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf4ee3716abf4562fe1a

I've never had issues with this before, the type of object I'm expecting back is of type `KeyValuePair<LoginTypes, Profile>` where `LoginTypes` is defined as

```
public enum LoginTypes
{
    LoginSuccessful,
    AccountCreationSuccessful,
    LinkSuccessful,
    Fail,
}
```

And `Profile` is defined as

```
public class Profile
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Uuid { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FacebookUUID { get; set; }
    public string LinkedinUUID { get; set; }
    public string TwitterUUID { get; set; }
    public string FacebookURL { get; set; }
    public string TwitterURL { get; set; }
    public string LinkedinURL { get; set; }
    public string DeviceToken { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string TwitterScreenName { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The error is suggesting the server is returning an invalid response that your client is not expecting. Please update your question to post the raw HTTP Request / HTTP Response that your server is returning, you can get this using Fiddler.

Comment: Second that comment^ . You need to look at the full response that is causing the exception as it is showing the start of an HTML/XML response, not a JSON one.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting Fiddler to work with Xamarin and an iOS device. This may take some time

Comment: This might help: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2011/12/06/configuring-fiddler-to-capture-web-traffic-from-an-iphone-ipad-device/

Comment: So I followed that tutorial step-by-step, but I couldn't get my iPhone to access the proxy site in order to download the certificate. Also, the problem I posted seems to have fixed itself, for some reason it just started working a few days ago without any intervention by myself